# Black Screen during Screen Share in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I don't know where to ask, so I am asking here. While having an online meeting, whenever I share my screen it always shows as a black screen with my cursor to other people in the meeting. It doesn't matter which platform I am using be it Skype, Google Meet, Zoom, or any other. In windows, there is no problem like this.  
OS - UBUNTU 18.04 
Graphics Card - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 
Please, Help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 40):

The default Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver installation comes with Wayland enabled. The objective is to disable Wayland and enable Xorg display server instead.

You might need to update GDM3 custom configuration file

> `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Uncommenting this will force the login screen to use Xorg.

> `#WaylandEnable=false`

After making the changes, reboot the system and voila, it worked for me!

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 21.04 too

Comment: This did the trick on my arch machine using amdgpu driver with ryzen 7 4800h. Thank you very much!

Comment: this worked for kali 2021 as well. Thanks mate (y) :)

Answer (score 11):

Read this [article](https://www.secjuice.com/wayland-vs-xorg/) to know more about this problem. Actually, this problem happens because of the **Wayland display server**. The first answer is about changing Wayland(newer and more secure but not more stable than Xorg) back to Xorg. If you want to stay in Wayland this solution helps to fix the problem in chrome. Not for all desktop apps you have.

**Mode Investigation**

Check which session you are using with the command:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland
```

There are some wrappers and tools to try to make it easy for an X11 app to move to Wayland, but it seems that nothing is perfect. And this is another case.

**Solution for Chrome**

At last, it seems that Chrome is doing the move to PipeWire, but not by default. It must be enabled as an experimental flag, with this in a tab address.Type this in address bar:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer
```

**Enable the experimental Feature and relaunch Chrome**, now the connection works well. Now Chrome uses the system selection window for sharing the screen or a window. Also, Teams works well in Chrome over Wayland, and the black screen + mouse is now solved.

Comment: In Ubuntu LTS 22.04.1 screen sharing via Zoom works out of the box with Wayland, but not Slack which only shares black screens or specific windows and tabs. I wonder if switching from Wayland to Xorg would cause Zoom to break or if they were clever enough to keep both working?

Answer (score 3):

Fix #1:

1. Install `xcompmgr` using your Linux distro's package manager.

```
sudo apt install xcompmgr
```

2. After installing, open the terminal and run this command:

```
xcompmgr -c -l0 -t0 -r0 -o.00
```

3. Open `compton.conf`

```
gedit ~/.config/compton.conf
```

4. Edit the following line:

```
shadow-exclude = [ "name = 'cpt_frame_window' " ];
```

Fix #2:
Run Ubuntu on Xorg instead of Wayland.

Comment: "E: Unable to locate package compositor" while installing compositor & `xcompmgr -c -l0 -t0 -r0 -o.00` gives "Another composite manager is already running (0x200012)".

Comment: However the problem has been resolved by changing from "Wayland" to "X11".

Comment: Alright, I should add that in answer.

Comment: Can you please update your what your fix #1 is doing, and why, rather than just list the steps? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In KUbuntu 18.04+ none of the above solutions worked for me for the Zoom APP, neither the [official solution written in Zoom support](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/202082128-Black-Screen-During-Screen-Sharing). I have a Nvidia 2080 GPU.

In order to fix it, I had to open the app "Compositor" in KDE menu and select the render engine to "XRender" instead of any of the OpenGL engines (v2.0, v3.1).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this which was screen related.
Fixed it by going to the screen settings by pressing the on-screen menu button -> 'multi-window settings' -> 'multi-windows modes' and setting it to "off".
Im not sure what this feature is for, but it seems like a side effect of it is to make a large black rectangle in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For Rocky Linux/Fedora/Red Hat - find file in

`/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

And uncomment - line -

`#WaylandEnable=false` to `WaylandEnable=false`

And Restart PC.