# Switching from wayland to xorg makes mouse weird

Tags: xorg, mouse, 22.04, touchscreen, wayland

So I was trying to fix this streaming issue, in which my screen was completely black, and I disabled wayland for xorg

[Black Screen during Screen Share in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270710/black-screen-during-screen-share-in-ubuntu-18-04)

I used the guide above.

The black window was fixed but more problems arose.

After rebooting, I noticed that my mouse acted weird and touch events were bringing up an virtual keyboard.

After changing it back to wayland, all of my above problems are fixed.

Anyone have any idea why?

Edit: here's my device specs

[image: specs]

Comment: What are your system specifications (model number of touch screen/graphics card, etc.)?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi done